# Linux mint increase cursor size beyond default max

Tags: linux, linux-mint

So I am using Linux mint and I have a 4k monitor so my cursor size is very very small. I have tried increasing it through Preferences->general and this worked but it is still very very small. Can this be increased through linux terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following where XX is the custom size entered as an integer.

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-size XX
```

The default small one should be something like 24.

Comment: Sorry if I did not mention this before, I am on mint linux 17 and the above command seems to do nothing. Is a reboot required?

Comment: Maybe a reload of the GUI, or at least a reload of the mouse section but I don't know what command to do that. I haven't used Mint in a while.

Comment: I have tried that, It seems that the value increases up until 50, then anything above that does not move. Is there a place I change this maximum?

Comment: It should have been able to go higher but I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: CMOS, It seems that it depends on your selected cursor theme. Some supports cursor resizing, some don't. Currently, my best choice is «redglass» from the «xcursor-themes» package, but the «ComixCursors» are nice too but smaller (i.e. you need to configure a larger value for the custom size). The «dmz-cursor-theme», «breeze-cursor-theme», «oxygen-cursor-theme» & «oxygen-cursor-theme-extra» packages also contains resizable cursors.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone here wants to reduce beyond min size then use a negative number in place os XX in above command

Comment: not os it is   "of"